# Please How would i get the search box to to disappear in (mobile View) and have only search glyphicon?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

[image]

Please How would i get the search box to to disappear in (mobile View) and have only search glyphicon? only when magnify glass/ glyphicon-search is pressed the search box appears? Thank You!

Comment: which bootstrap version are you using? also, please share the code properly using code block.

Comment: @xuhaib im sorry for the delayed response it is bootstrap3 im having issues with code block can i share it on js bin? forgive me im novice at best with this!

Comment: you can share the code on js bin.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/pikifaziha/1/edit?html,output  *// i just want to click on the search glyphicon and make the search box appear,thank you!

Answer (score 1):

add media query and add attribute as display="none" for `search box` only, and for search glyphicon you can either use display="block".

follow this sample:

### css:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     .searchBox{
       display:none;
     }
     .searchIcon{
      display: block;
     }
 }
```

### html:

```
<div>
 <input class="searchBox" type="search" name="searchBox" 
  placeholder="search">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search searchIcon"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: THANKS but i should have said i wanted that "glyphicon glyphicon-search" to be A <a href="#" for live link, its kind of working but its moving one of the <li>Home link in the header menu and adding about 50px of padding or margin, also the magnify glass is showing up with the word search next to it and A background, but the search box did disappear in mobile screen size, Any other clues Thank you again !

Comment: give me your view(html) snapshot to my mail id imsumit0303@gmail.com